# How to check if an object is of instance `Type`?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a function as follow

```
void (Type type, dynamic instance) {
  // Unable to do this
  if (instance is type) {
  }
}
```

I want to check if the instance passed is of the same type as the passed `type`. The `type` can be a base class and the `instance` can be the implementation of the base class, so just `(instance.runtimeType == type)` won't suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do so using a runtime `Type` object.

To achieve something similar, you'll have to use generic functions instead:

```
void foo<T>(dynamic instance) {
  if (instance is T) {

  }
}
```

Comment: I agree completely. A `Type` object is a dumb token intended for use with `dart:mirrors`. All you can do to `Type` objects is to check if they refer to that same type. If you want to use it as a *type* (check if something is an instance of it, use it as a type argument), you need to pass the type as a type argument. You can always convert a type argument to a `Type` object, but you cannot go in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a limited way to test that like using `type.toString()`

```
if('$type' == 'SomeClassName')
```

Comment: I can already do that, but I need to check for subclass/superclass relation.

Comment: I think you are out of luck here.